Keeping the splash screen displayed until the desktop is shown
I have successfully changed my splash screen on Raspberry Pi OS (Version 11 Bullseye) and removed the Plymouth status messages during the display of the splash screen. Now I want to keep the splash screen displayed until the desktop environment appears. How do I do that?
